# swipe tab layout, changes icon on toolbar

Tags: java, android, swipe, android-toolbar, android-tablayout

how to create display toolbar change icon in tab layout as in Line Messenger ?
I've been trying to figure out, but it never worked.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYDS7.jpg)

Sorry my english is not good . Thanks  !

Answer (score 0):

You can use *invalidateOptionsMenu()*, and the o*nCreateOptionsMenu()* method will be recalled, so you can decide to inflate another XML-Menu layout.

Good luck